# review based app using mongoDB `mongoose`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to build (Stores and Products) review app but I am not quiet sure about building the review schema

what I have done so far is that i made it general for both like this

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
comment: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 100,
    maxlength: 250,
  },
  rate: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
  },
  reported: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I have created my routes like this

```
app.use("/api/stores", storesRoute);
app.use("/api/stores/:id/reviews", reviewsRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productsRoute);
app.use("/api/products/:id/reviews", reviewsRoute);
```

my concern is how to know if i'm dealing with a store or product in this regard ?
should i add a property on review schema for this or should i make a review schema for each separately ?

Comment: What do you want to have reviews? Both products and stores?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: I suggest making separate schema for reviews each and using references of products and store separately. It would make easier for future aggregations.

Comment: @Raffi  If both, then I guess you can include the reviews schema inside each of products and stores schemas, where `reviews` is a field with type of `[reviewSchema]` (Array).

Comment: @BlackMath and do you think this will be future proof if I would like to make changes in the future ?

Comment: @Raffi If you make changes in the sub schema reviewSchema, then these changes will automatically be reflected on the field `reviews` because they are of type `reviewSchema`. That's all I can think of for changes in the future, unless you have a specific thing in mind you would like to share.